# Change Grid item column order on small screens

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to have a grid looking like this for larger displays:

[image]

and this for smaller sizes:

[image]

Currently the skeleton of my grid is succinctly like this:

```js
<Fragment>
  <Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <img src={img1} />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <Paper>Text Content 1...</Paper>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>

  <Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <Paper>Text Content 2...</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
      <img src={img2} />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Fragment>
```

How can I do such as in mobile view (width 12) the first `Grid item` from the second `Grid container` (Text content 2) displays after (below) the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this:

```
<Grid container>
          <Grid spacing={3} container item xs={12} md={12}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} className={classes.item}>
              <img
                width="50px"
                src="https://cdn3.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/37/37/simple-cartoon-a-cute-bear-vector-18823737.jpg"
                alt="abc"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={12} md={6} className={classes.item}>
              <Paper>Text Content 1...</Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Grid container item spacing={3} xs={12} md={12} className="flexgrid">
            <Grid container item xs={12} md={6} className={classes.item}>
              <Paper>Text Content 2...</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container item xs={12} md={6} className={classes.item}>
              <img
                width="50px"
                src="https://cdn3.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/37/37/simple-cartoon-a-cute-bear-vector-18823737.jpg"
                alt="abd"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[SOURCE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-grid-stacking-forked-7ibv5)

[PREVIEW](https://7ibv5.csb.app/)

for re-order added:

```
<Grid container item spacing={3} xs={12} md={12} className="flexgrid">
```

and css :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .flexgrid{
    flex-direction: column-reverse
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but your snippet produces actually the default result. I'm looking to have "Text content 2" BELOW the image for the second grid on mobile.

Comment: demo and source updated, see preview again

Comment: With a bit of tweaking (I'm using a Parallax component for the images) and eliminating the `spacing={3}` that adds some nasty margin on the right, this will work, I believe. Thank you very much!